# how to update the value of a string given to a div.innerHTML value by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have been working on a library app that has functions like add, `remove`, `edit/toggle`. I can't seen to find out how to update the value given to the the read property which are `"yes"` and `"not-yet"` . Once the shownBook element display all I can do is remove it. How could make the edit/toggle funtional so `read.value` can be updated?

````
let titleInput =  document.getElementsByClassName('title')
titleInput[0].setAttribute('id', 'title')
let authorInput = document.getElementsByClassName('author')
authorInput[0].setAttribute('id', 'author')

let titleId = document.getElementById('title')
let authorId = document.getElementById('author')```
let noPages = document.getElementById('nopages')
let read = document.getElementById('read')


let addBook = document.getElementById('addB')


addBook.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let shownBook = document.createElement('div')
  let editToggle = document.createElement('button')
  Let remove = document.createElement('button')
  remove.innerHTML = 'remove'
  editToggle.innerHTML = 'edit'
  let div = document.createElement('div')

  let NewBook = {
    title: titleId.value,
    author: authorId.value,
    noPages: noPages.value,
    read: read.value
  }

  let emptyArr = []
  for (let u in NewBook) {
    emptyArr.push(NewBook[u])
  }

  let addedBook = new Book(...emptyArr)

  let string = JSON.stringify(addedBook)
  shownBook.innerHTML = string.replace(/[{}]/g, '')
  shownBook.appendChild(div)
  div.appendChild(remove)
  div.appendChild(editToggle)

  remove.addEventListener('click', () => {
    shownBook.style.display = 'none'
  })

 editToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if(shownBook.innerHTML.includes('yes')){
    shownBook.innerHTML.replace('yes', 'not-yet')
   }else if(shownBook.innerHTML.includes('not-yet')){
    shownBook.innerHTML.replace('not-yet', 'yes')
   }
})

})
````

```
   <div class="form ">
        <div id="tit">Tittle </div>
        <input class="title" type="text" placeholder="type here"/> 
        <div id="aut">Author</div>
        <input class="author" type="text" placeholder="type here"/>
        <div id="pages">No. pages</div>
        <input id="nopages" type="number" min="0">
        <div class="read">Read</div>
       
        <select id="read">
            <option value="yes">yes</option>
            <option value="not-yet">not yet </option>
        </select>
            
      <div id="addB"><button id="addB22">add</button></div>

      
    </div>
```

since `shownBook.innerHTML` is detected as a string I tried replacing the `"yes"` with `"not-yet"` and
vice versa  by clicking `editToggle` but does not do anything
now here is an example of  what `shownBook` looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript strings are *immutable*. Calling `replace` will not modify the existing string, only return a new string. You need to assign the new string.

```js
editToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
   if(shownBook.innerHTML.includes('yes')){
    shownBook.innerHTML = shownBook.innerHTML.replace('yes', 'not-yet')
   }else if(shownBook.innerHTML.includes('not-yet')){
    shownBook.innerHTML = shownBook.innerHTML.replace('not-yet', 'yes')
   }
})
```